# Map key null not found in map

Tags: apex, visualforce, error, null

I want to render a specific column based on the some conditions, the first is that a flag should be "TRUE" and the second is that the The ids should be the sames, like that, if a click on a specific row,  only that row will be rendered but i get an error and i do not know why ?

> Map key null not found in map.
>   Error is in expression: '{!IF(AND(flag_placement,map_condidat_cv[key].Placement__c ==
>   IDplacement), TRUE, FALSE)}' in component

Here is my code :

```visualforce
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!map_condidat_cv}" var="key" style="width:100%" >
     <apex:column  headerValue="Placement" value ="{!map_condidat_cv[key].Placement__r.name}" onclick="showPlacement('{!map_condidat_cv[key].Placement__c}')" rendered= "{!flag_placement == false}"/>
     <apex:column  headerValue="Placement"  rendered="{!IF(AND(flag_placement,map_condidat_cv[key].Placement__c == IDplacement), TRUE, FALSE)}">
     <apex:outputpanel>
              <a href="#myAnchor"> Voir Plus de détail sur le placement </a>
     </apex:outputpanel>
</apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Note : IDplacement is an ID passed from the apex controller and  i want to make sure that only the row with this ID will react .

Comment: Have you tried to check the key, whether it is NULL or not? Something like this: `{!IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(key)),flag_placement,map_condidat_cv[key].Placement__c == IDplacement), TRUE, FALSE)}`

Comment: i will try it  now

Comment: no error, but all rows have been rendered as if they all have the same ID

Comment: I would suggest avoiding having a null key in the `map_condidat_cv` i.e. fix the problem in the controller.

Comment: when i try with this  '{!NOT(ISNULL(map_condidat_cv[key].Placement__c))}' , it gives me the same  error,  WHY ?

Comment: i think in your case the value of key is null and not the map_condidat_cv[key].Placement__c. i would make sure the value of key is not null

Comment: If you are going to use map_condidat_cv[key] in your Visualforce, then there must be an entry in the map for every key you intend to use. Testing with ISNULL won't help because it fails at the point of reading a value from the map. In the constructor of your controller, you could have map_condidat_cv.put(null, null) and/or map_condidat_cv.put(key, null) for all keys you might use. Then it would work in the way that you expect.

Comment: No, if i remove the condition ''{!NOT(ISNULL(map_condidat_cv[key].Placement__c))}'' all the fields works and are rendered, to test the existence of the key i created a column that prints out that key after the condition and it works so i do not understand the origin of this error

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm having a hard time believing this, it would appear that `somemap[key]` expressions can't be used in the `rendered=` attribute of `apex:column` -- even if all of the map keys are non-null.

Assuming a map `map_condidat_cv` of `<String,Account>` where the key is the account.name and hence the key must be present as account.name is required, then

fails **Map key not found in map**

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!map_condidat_cv}" var="key" style="width:100%" > 
 <apex:column  headerValue="Placement" rendered="{!LEFT(map_condidat_cv[key].id,3) = '001'}" > 
    <apex:outputpanel >
          <a href="#myAnchor"> Voir Plus de détail sur le placement {!key}</a>
    </apex:outputpanel>
 </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

but move the rendered expression to the `apex:outputPanel` and **it works fine**:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!map_condidat_cv}" var="key" style="width:100%" >
 <apex:column  headerValue="Placement" > 
    <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!LEFT(map_condidat_cv[key].id,3) = '001'}" >
          <a href="#myAnchor"> Voir Plus de détail sur le placement {!key}</a>
    </apex:outputpanel>
 </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

You are going to have to rethink how to handle the column render, perhaps by using a wrapper class in the controller with a Boolean getter on each element `isVis`.

[some somewhat-related answers with VF map keys here.](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44828/map-key-null-not-found-in-map-when-using-apexpageblocktable)