# Map key null not found in map for properly built map

Tags: apex, visualforce, map, custom-controller, repeat

I have a controller that builds a map from `CaseNumber`s to arrays of booleans, which decide how to render a column on a table: `public Map<String, Boolean[]> caseMap { get; set; }`

After setting up the map I use `System.debug` to ensure everything is in the map.
The cases are filtered so that only a certain record type is selected like this:

```
public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon {
        get {
            if(setCon == null) {
                setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
                    [SELECT Id, CaseNumber, Subject, Status, Expected_Start_Date__c, Expected_Close_Date__c, RecordType.Name FROM Case
                   WHERE RecordType.Name = 'rm']));
            }
            return setCon;
        }
        set;
    }

public MyController() {
        this.cases = setCon.getRecords();
...
```

The way the map is built is by looping over `this.cases` and inserting a boolean array in it:

```
for(Case c : this.cases) {
    System.debug('Case: ' + c.CaseNumber);

    // init array
    Boolean[] barr = new Boolean[nmonths];

    // setup array
    ...
    System.debug('Finished setting up boolean array: ' + string.valueOf(barr));

    // Put boolean array into map
    caseMap.put(c.CaseNumber, barr);
}
```

In my VF page I do:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!cases}" var="rmcase">
        <apex:column value="{!rmcase.CaseNumber}"/>
        <apex:repeat value="{!caseMap[rmcase.CaseNumber]}" var="rbool">
            <column value="foo"/>
        </apex:repeat> 
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

However this returns:

```
Map key null not found in map
Error is in expression '{!caseMap[rmcase.CaseNumber]}' in component <apex:pageBlockTable> in page rmoverview
```

This is completely /ridiculous/ as I have checked and there are no `null`s inside the `cases` list. There are 20 cases and these are the case in `caseMap`.

How can I dig further into this problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: Something like this: fir loop to populate the map and avoid the null error for(Case c : this.cases) { caseMap.put(c.CaseNumber, new Boolean[]);}  then for(Case c : this.cases) { /*before placing values check if the key exist in the map*/ if(case.containsKey(c.CaseNumber))   caseMap.put(c.CaseNumber, barr; }

Comment: Does the running user have access to the CaseNumber field? How ares you populating `cases`. Error is basically saying that `encase.casenumber` is NULL so review your code / page for all possibilities for that field to be null.

Comment: is `caseMap` instantiated in the controller before the page displays?

Comment: @cropredy yes, it's instantiated in the controller constructor as `this.caseMap = new Map<String, Boolean[]>();` and defined as a field as `public Map<String, Boolean[]> caseMap { get; set; }`

Comment: @Lily, I came across an interesting known issue link related to your problem. Looks like, this error occurs when the value for that key in the map is null. Follow this link pls-https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T3k2AAC

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly why yet, but it is something to do with the `apex:pageBlockTable` iterating over the map keys. If you swap it out with a basic `apex:repeat` it works fine.

E.g. Change this:

```
<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!cases}" var="rmcase"> 
        <apex:column value="{!rmcase.CaseNumber}"/>
        <apex:repeat value="{!caseMap[rmcase.CaseNumber]}" var="rbool">
            <column value="foo"/>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

To:

```
<table>
    <apex:repeat value="{!caseMap}" var="idx">
    <tr>
        <td>{!idx}</td>
        <apex:repeat value="{!caseMap[idx]}" var="r_col">
            <td>{!r_col}</td>
        </apex:repeat>
    </tr>
    </apex:repeat>
</table>
```

For reference, this is the basic controller I used.

```
public class CaseController {
    public Map<string, Boolean[]> caseMap { get; set; }
    public List<Case> cases { get; set; }

    public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon {
        get {
            if(setCon == null) {
                setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
                    [SELECT Id, CaseNumber, Subject, Status, RecordType.Name FROM Case]));
            }
            return setCon;
        }
        set;
    }

    public CaseController() {
        this.cases = setCon.getRecords();

        this.caseMap = new Map<string, Boolean[]>();

        for(Case c : this.cases) {           
            integer nmonths = 2;
            // init array
            Boolean[] barr = new Boolean[nmonths];
            for(integer i = 0; i < nmonths; i++) {
                barr[i] = false;
            }

            // Put boolean array into map
            System.assertNotEquals(null, c.CaseNumber);
            System.assertNotEquals('', c.CaseNumber);
            caseMap.put(c.CaseNumber, barr);
        }
    }

}
```

---

Just playing around, something very fishy is going on with the map key access in the inner repeat.

Input:
`<apex:repeat value="{!caseMap[rmcase.CaseNumber]}" var="r">`

> Map key null not found in map
>   Error is in expression '{!caseMap[rmcase.CaseNumber]}' in component  in page casespage

Input: `<apex:repeat value="{!caseMap[rmcase.CaseNumber + '']}" var="r">`

> Map key null not found in map
>   Error is in expression '{!caseMap[rmcase.CaseNumber + '']}' in component  in page casespage

Input: `<apex:repeat value="{!caseMap[rmcase.CaseNumber + '00001033']}" var="r">` produces

> Map key 0000103300001033 not found in map
>   Error is in expression '{!caseMap[rmcase.CaseNumber + '00001033']}' in component  in page casespage

Note how in the last case it decides the map key is no longer null.

It's something around how the parent apex:pageBlockTable is sending the CaseNumber into the apex:Repeat as the key because the following doesn't fall over on the key.

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!cases}" var="rmcase"> 
    <apex:column value="{!rmcase.CaseNumber}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!caseMap['00001033']}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!caseMap[rmcase.CaseNumber]}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

For reference, there are other occurrences of problems with keys not working correctly within apex:pageBlockTable:

- ['Map key null not found in map' when using apex:pageBlockTable](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/44828/102)
- [Map key null not found in map](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/114777/102)